# How to do a Join if it passes a condition?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I would like to do an **if** statement within my query, but I'm not sure how.  I want to perform:

```
join asoc2 in Personnels
on comp.Secondary_associate equals asoc2.Dpinitials
```

if there is a Second_Person data available.  Any ideas how to do this?  Let me know if there's an easier way.  Here's my complete query:

```
(from sc in Data
join comp in Companies
on sc.Company equals comp.Company
join anl in Personnels  
on sc.SalesP_initials equals anl.Dpinitials
join asoc1 in Personnels
on comp.First_associate equals asoc1.Dpinitials
join asoc2 in Personnels
on comp.Second_Person equals asoc2.Dpinitials
select new {
MyCompany = sc.Company,
ReleaseDate = sc.Release_date,  
WebHeadline = sc.Short_subject,
EmailTo =   
    anl.Last_name + ", " + anl.First_name + " <" + anl.Email_address.Trim() + ">; " 
    + 
    asoc1.Last_name + ", " + asoc1.First_name + " <" + asoc1.Email_address.Trim() + ">; " 
    +
    asoc2.Last_name + ", " + asoc2.First_name + " <" + asoc2.Email_address.Trim() + ">"
}).FirstOrDefault ()
```

Right now, it just displays null because *comp.Second_Person* doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you try adding `where comp.Second_Person != null` after all joins and before select new?

Comment: When you eschew the query comprehension syntax and instead use the method-chaining style it becomes trivial to conditionally compose the various pieces and parts of your query based on runtime values.

Comment: @KirkWoll would you provide some details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "where" in linq to filter your data